# Python - Duvida- transformar em Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

bom dia!
Gente conectei usando python no banco Sql usando pymssql

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server='nomeservidor', user='usuario', password='senha', 
database='banco')
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)

cursor.execute('SELECT ROTAID,DESCRICAO FROM ROTAS')
for row in cursor:
    print("%d,%s" % (row['ROTAID'], row['DESCRICAO']))
conn.close()
```

porém ele me traz os dados nesse formato abaixo

```
2,ROTA 02
3,ROTA 03
4,ROTA 04
5,ROTA 05
6,ROTA 06
7,ROTA 07
```

Gostaria de transformar em um Dataframe em tabela como abaixo, teria como ?

```
ROTAID  DESCRICAO
2        ROTA 02
3        ROTA 03
4        ROTA 04
5        ROTA 05
6        ROTA 06
7        ROTA 07
```

agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Já tentou `df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())`

Answer (score 0):

A biblioteca `pandas` possui um método específico para criar um dataframe a partir de uma query `SQL`. O método é o [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html)

```
df = pandas.read_sql_query("SELECT ROTAID,DESCRICAO FROM ROTAS", con=cursor)
```

O comando acima deve ser suficiente.

Answer (score -3):

```
import pandas as pd    

cursor.execute('SELECT ROTAID,DESCRICAO FROM ROTAS')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ROTAID", "DESCRICAO"])
for row in cursor:
   df = df.append({
                  "ROTAID": row['ROTAID'],
                  "DESCRICAO": row['DESCRICAO']
                  }, ignore_index=True)
conn.close()
```

Comment: show deu certo obg man!